# After publish asp.net-core application show wrong login page with message "Use another service to log in"

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, identity, asp.net-core-2.2

After publish asp.net core application load default login page - not my.

With message:

> Use another service to log in.
>   There are no external authentication services configured. See this article for details on setting up this ASP.NET application to support logging in via external services.

I use Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.EntityFrameworkCore.

```
    public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env)
    {
        if (env.IsDevelopment())
        {
            app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
        }
        else
        {
            app.UseExceptionHandler("/Home/Error");
            app.UseHsts();
        }

        app.UseStatusCodePages(async context =>
        {
            if (context.HttpContext.Response.StatusCode == 403)
            {
                app.UseStatusCodePagesWithRedirects("~/Identity/Account/Login");
            }
        });

        app.UseSession();
        app.UseHttpsRedirection();
        app.UseStaticFiles();

        app.UseCookiePolicy();
        app.UseAuthentication();

        app.UseIdentity();

        CreateSignalRRouts(app);

        app.UseMvc(routes =>
        {
            routes.MapRoute(name: "areas", template: "{area:exists}/{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}");
            routes.MapRoute(name: "default", template: "{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}");
        });
    }
```

When I start application straight from Visual Studio login page work correct. I found several similar posts but no answers

Comment: How did you publish your application? Is there any demo to reproduce your issue?

Comment: Right-click on my project and select _Publish..._ I have created a profile for the target location is the folder. Next, in IIS I have added an application where her location is my publishing file. No application will be available only to work on the internet and the problem occurs on my development machine and the production computer. Only in debug works correctly but when I  _Publish..._ debug version did not work;/ eh

Comment: Is there any demo to reproduce your issue?

Comment: it is not a large application now extended with login from identity. I will try to prepare a demo.